# Is there a way to implement SSL for HTTP calls using JKS Keystore or Truststore in Groovy?

Tags: ssl, groovy, apache-nifi, keystore, truststore

I have written a groovy script to run via Nifi's ExecuteGroovyScript processor. It runs fine. However, I am wondering if there is a way to implement this using SSL?

I have JKS Keystore and Truststore JKS files on my unix server.

Below is the code which I have written:

```
def flowFile = session.get()

def postResult=''
def url = new URL("https://xxx.xxx.xxx/sample?key=8B4B4565-313E-462D-8160-175F6F456773")
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection()
connection.setRequestMethod("GET")
// connection.setConnectTimeout(10000)
connection.connect()
if (connection.responseCode == 200 || connection.responseCode == 201) {
    flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'api_responce_code', connection.responseCode.toString())
    flowFile = session.write(flowFile, {outputStream -> outputStream.write(connection.content.getBytes())} as OutputStreamCallback)
    session.transfer(flowFile,REL_SUCCESS)
} else {
    flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'api_responce_code', connection.responseCode.toString())
    flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'api_responce_error', connection.getErrorStream().toString())
    session.transfer(flowFile,REL_FAILURE)
}
```

Comment: Why not use the InvokeHTTP or GetHTTP processors to do this?

Comment: We want to add different kinds of API requests and authentication mechanisms into our flow. Best would be to have just a single ExecuteGroovyScript processor than have many multiple processors which include InvokeHttp. Correct me if there is an alternate way, then I'm open for it too